# How to create new column in data.table based on presence of value in another data.table

Tags: r

I have two data.tables A and B:

```
A               B                          A
---------       -----------------          -----------------
Col1 Col2       Col1 Col2                  Col1 Col2 Col3  
A    1          A    popular               A    1    popular 
B    2          B    moderate        ->    B    2    moderate
C    3          C    not popular           .    .    .
D    4          D    popular               .    .    .
```

For each value in col1 of A, I want to check for its existence in col1 of B. If it's there, then create a third column in A based on the value in col2 of B. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `join`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)[B, Col3 := Col2,on = .(Col1)]
```

Comment: R is great. Thanks!